# Classification test set accuracy lower than validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, training-data

My validation set is having high accuracy for classification. But low on test data as data is not balanced. Please suggest here.

What could be the reason for getting high accuracy on the validation set but low accuracy on the test set?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are overfitting on the test set, but it is impossible to say for sure, as your question only barely describes what you are doing. What kind of problem do you have? Multi-label, multi-class? Or something more simple? How do you measure accuracy? How many classes? Which framework do you use?

Take a good look at your data and its distributions. If they are unbalanced, balance them *before* training. There is no point in doing vanilla training of a network on two classes, if the distribution is 1:99. You must address this issue, either via re-balancing your dataset (e.g., by oversampling the underrepresented class) or by suitably modifying your loss function.

Assuming the issue is not balancing but [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), use [data augmentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-for-deep-learning-4fe21d1a4eb9) and [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)#Regularization_in_statistics_and_machine_learning). Some possible things to try are to reduce the model capacity (fewer parameters) and to add something like [dropout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_(neural_networks)) and/or [weight decay](https://towardsdatascience.com/this-thing-called-weight-decay-a7cd4bcfccab).